# Regex to match a simple math equation within a string

Tags: php, regex, matching

For example, if there was this string:

`what is 4+3`, or, `what is 3 * 2`, or, `what is 3x2`, or, `what is 4 times 2`, how would this be accomplished? Is it possible to create such a matching system in regex?

Comment: I'm unsure what you actually want to accomplish. Some examples of input and expected output would clarify.

Comment: First, you need define all possible operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following samples are all matched.

```
$samples = Array(
  'what is 4+3',
  'what is 2 plus 7',
  'what is 3 * 2',
  'what is 3x2',
  'what is 4 times 2'
);

foreach($samples as $sample) {
  $sample = preg_replace('/(times)|\*/', 'x', $sample);
  $sample = str_replace('plus', '+', $sample);
  preg_match('/what is \d ?[+x] ?\d/', $sample, $matches);
  var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

A bit nicer in JavaScript. Just including this for the fun of it.

```js
var samples = [
  'what is 4+3',
  'what is 2 plus 7',
  'what is 3 * 2',
  'what is 3x2',
  'what is 4 times 2'
];

samples.forEach(function(sample) {
  sample = sample
    .replace(/(times)|\*/, 'x')
    .replace('plus', '+')
  ;
  var match = sample.match(/what is \d ?[+x] ?\d/);
  console.log(match);
});
```

Comment: For sure, OP is lucky some of us enjoy a hot date with capturing groups on a Saturday Night :). Nice approach.

Comment: Thanks folks. It's very nice that you all helped.

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are literally `What is <equation>` you can do this

```
What is (\d+ ?([^\s] ?\d+ ?))
```

To match variable length equations (`4 + 11 times 2` for example), you can do this.

```
What is (\d+ ?([^\s] ?\d+ ?)+)
```

The results you want are in capture group #1.

Comment: Hmm, your perspective just reminded me how very vague the question is. I went for a more literal approach :)

Comment: Thanks folks. It's very nice that you all helped.